# Unable to make AngularJS Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my first time with AngularJS Routing, I have made a master HTML file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head ng-app="RateRequestApp">
    <title> - Shipment Details</title>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="Angular/App.js"></script>
    <script src="Angular/Controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ReadOnlyController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#ShipmentDetails"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#rate-request"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="main">
    <span>data need to come here</span>
        <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And app.js

```
var RateRequestApp = angular.module('RateRequestApp', [
   'RateRequestApp.controllers',
   'ngRoute'
]);
RateRequestApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/ShipmentDetails', {

            templateUrl: 'ShipmentDetails.html',
            controller: 'ReadOnlyController'
        })
        .when('/rate-request', {
            templateUrl: 'rate-request.html',
            controller: 'RateRequestCtrl'
        });
});
```

Controllers.js

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller('ReadOnlyController', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Success";
    }
]);
```

I can't see any error in console. The app is simply not working.
And my URL comes like this

```
http://localhost:61919/home.html#ShipmentDetails
```

Everything looks okay to me. Can any one point out What I am doing wrong here?

**My complete App: http://plnkr.co/edit/0f14nrITRb9ioXunEdot**

Comment: I *do* see errors in console on http://plnkr.co/edit/0f14nrITRb9ioXunEdot?p=preview ... One of it is: `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'RateRequestApp' is not available!` More, on the 'network' tab you can see `Angular/App.js` and `Angular/Controller.js` can't be found...

Comment: Your .js files are in the root, not in an "Angular" folder. In your Plnkr at least.

Comment: @cfj Sorry, Corrected now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are lots of errors in the console.
So lets start

1.You do not have Angular directory

```
<script src="Angular/App.js"></script>
<script src="Angular/Controllers.js"></script>
```

it should be

```
<script src="App.js"></script>
<script src="Controllers.js"></script>
```

2. `ng-app` on `body` not `head`
3. You have to use `ng-href` directive it should be like this :

   `<a ng-href='#/ShipmentDetails'>Details</a>`

And you do not have `RateRequestCtrl` - check App.js.

Fixed example : http://plnkr.co/edit/beRwB2gAccPDcgRsicjU?p=preview